# Function argument implementing two traits

Tags: rust

So let's take this code with two structs implementing two traits. How can I make a function that takes as argument any struct that implement both traits ?

```rust
pub trait Router {
    fn route(&self);
}

pub trait Library {
    fn do_math(&self);
}
pub struct Pair1 {}

impl Library for Pair1 {
    fn do_math(&self) {
        println!("Doing math");
    }
}

impl Router for Pair1 {
    fn route(&self) {
        println!("Routing");
    }
}

pub struct Pair2 {}

impl Library for Pair2 {
    fn do_math(&self) {
        println!("Doin math");
    }
}

impl Router for Pair2 {
    fn route(&self) {
        println!("Routin");
    }
}
```

Here is the solution I tried:

```rust
pub trait RouterAndLibrary: Router + Library {}
impl<T: Router + Library> RouterAndLibrary for T {}

pub fn my_fn(
    pair: &mut Box<dyn RouterAndLibrary>
) {
    println!("Hello");
}

pub fn wrapper_fn() {
    let pair = Pair1 {};
    my_fn(pair);
}
```

But this throws an error: `mismatched types expected mutable reference "&mut Box<(dyn RouterAndLibrary + 'static)> found struct Pair1`.

Comment: Why are you using trait objects instead of generics?

Comment: Ohh .. There's actually no reasons not to, I just didn't think of it for some reason ! It works like a charm thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should probably favor generics instead of trait objects when possible. Statically-dispatched generics make this situation easy.

```
pub fn my_fn<T: Router + Library>(pair: &T) {
    println!("Hello");
}
```

That's the easy solution, and generally you should favor generics when possibly.

If you truly need a `dyn` trait object, then you've already discovered the best way to do it. You can't require multiple traits in a trait object type (with the exception of `Send` and `Sync`, which are baked into the compiler), because the virtual dispatch table in the wide pointer is associated to a single trait. so we need to make a new trait that contains the right dispatch information. We can easily do that *and* provide a blanket implementation, as you've already discovered.

```
pub trait RouterAndLibrary: Router + Library {}
impl<T: Router + Library> RouterAndLibrary for T {}
```

You just got a little carried away with `Box`. References themselves can contain unsized types, so your `dyn` solution would look like this.

```
pub fn my_fn(pair: &dyn RouterAndLibrary) {
    println!("Hello");
}
```

In either case, we can call the function as

```
my_fn(&pair);
```

The former function signature will monomorphize, and the latter will automatically produce a trait object for us with no explicit cast required.